# how do I group and sort this data with pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

i've got csv data of guitar manufacturers and the guitars - including the guitar type - they produce

```
vendor,product
fender,acoustic::paramount
fender,acoustic::newporter
fender,electric::telecaster
yamaha,acoustic::f335
yamaha,electric::pac012
```

How can I produce output of the total of each type of guitar per vendor, desc sorted by one of the guitar types (acoustic), e.g.

```
fender - acoustic:2, electric:1
yamaha - acoustic:1, electric:1
```

any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

**`1.If Sorting an array<struct> is optional:`**

Try with inbuilt **[groupBy,aggregate, collect_list, map_from_arrays](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#map_from_arrays)** functions to get the output required.

**`Example:`**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('fender','acoustic::paramount'),('fender','acoustic::newporter'),('fender','electric::telecaster'),('yamaha','acoustic::f335'),('yamaha','electric::pac012')],['vendor','product'])

#replace the characters after :: using regexp_repalce function
#group by vendor,product and get the count
df1 = df.withColumn("product",regexp_replace(col("product"),"(::.*)","")).groupBy("vendor","product").agg(count("*").alias("cnt"))

#groupby vendor and get the product, count as arrays
#now use map_from_arrays functions to map two arrays and create dictionary
#use to_json function to create a string from dictionary
#use regexp_replace to replace {,} from the string

df1.groupBy("vendor").agg(regexp_replace(to_json(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("product")),collect_list(col("cnt")))),"[\{|\}]","").alias("product")).show(10,False)
#+------+-------------------------+
#|vendor|product                  |
#+------+-------------------------+
#|yamaha|"acoustic":1,"electric":1|
#|fender|"acoustic":2,"electric":1|
#+------+-------------------------+
```

**`2.If Sorting an array<struct> is mandatory:`**

Use higher order transform functions with **`array_sort`** to sort the nested array then create a `map`, if you are looking for sorting an struct all the time.

**`Example:`**

```
df2 = df1.groupBy("vendor").agg(collect_list(struct(col("product"),col("cnt"))).alias("ms"))

#use higher order transform function then use array_sort to sort by count of values
#create a map by extracting product name and count then replace the array<dictionary> characters

df2.withColumn("sort_product",expr("array_sort(transform(ms,x->struct(x['product'] as product,x['cnt'] as count)))")).\
withColumn("sort_product",expr("regexp_replace(to_json(transform(sort_product,x -> map(x['product'],x['count']))),'[\\\\[|\\\\]|\{|\}]','')")).\
drop("ms").\
show(10,False)

#+------+-------------------------+
#|vendor|sort_product             |
#+------+-------------------------+
#|yamaha|"acoustic":1,"electric":1|
#|fender|"acoustic":2,"electric":1|
#+------+-------------------------+
```